# Can I see a list of which Nintendo eShop games I own somewhere?

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, club-nintendo

Spending the rest of my coins on Virtual Console games, and there's a lot of overlap between Wii, Wii U, 3DS. Just want to make sure I'm not buying one I already have somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: I keep a spreadsheet of which games I own. It helps in situations like this, or figuring out if I already have a PC game without having to check Steam, Origin, Desura, Uplay, Gamestop, physical discs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Nintendo FAQ](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/614/~/how-to-view-previously-downloaded-titles)

> 1. From the HOME Menu, select the Nintendo eShop icon and tap "Open."
> 2. On the upper left of the screen, tap "Menu."
> 3. Scroll down and select "Settings / Other."
> 4. Scroll down to the section titled "History," and select "Redownloadable Software."
> 5. Select "Your Downloads."
> 6. A list of previously downloaded titles will appear. Select a title, then follow the onscreen instructions to update or redownload it.

A less reliable method would be checking your Club Nintendo account, but this will only show products that you've registered, though if your Club Nintendo account was linked, eshop purchases were automatically registered on Club Nintendo ([linking accounts is no longer possible since the service is shutting down](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1099)).  To check your Club Nintendo products:

1. Log in to Club Nintendo
2. Go to "Account & Coins"
3. Click the "Products" tab